# NestJS Sequelize Model with multiple foreign keys for one column

Tags: nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I've been trying to wrack my brain regarding this, I'm not quite sure if it's possible either but I have this model:

```
export class FavouriteCompanies extends Model {
  @Column({ primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true })
  id: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @Column({ allowNull: false })
  userId: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => InternationalCompanies)
  @ForeignKey(() => LocalCompanies)
  @Column({
    allowNull: false,
  })
  companyId: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => User, 'userId')
  user: User;

  @BelongsTo(() => InternationalCompanies, 'id')
  internationalCompanies: InternationalCompanies;

  @BelongsTo(() => LocalCompanies, 'id')
  localCompanies: LocalCompanies;
}
```

I am trying to add multiple foreign keys to the column of `companyId` to create relationships between multiple tables. The `companyId` will be an integer value that can either be `InternationalCompanies.id` or `LocalCompanies.id`. But after adding this and running it, it seems like the only `ForeignKey` that get's registered is the first one which is `InternationalCompanies`. I've checked via generating a create table script on pg admin for the `FavouriteCompanies` table and it only seems to include one constraint, even though there's two set here. Is this possible?